# Large frequency behaviour of a class of Fourier sine integrals

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-transform

I have encountered recently several integrals of the form

$$
I(k)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \sin(kx)f(x)g\left(\sqrt{x^2+m^2}\right)
$$

Where $m$ is a real constant, and $f(x)\sim 1/x$ as $x\to 0$, but elsewhere is infinitely differentiable. $g(x) \sim x^{-n}e^{-x}$ as $x \to \infty$ for some $n>0$ and is infinitely differentiable. **Is it possible to say anything about the large $k$ behavior of $I(k)$?** Perhaps in terms of the derivatives of $f$ or $g$?

So far what I have done is make the replacement $\sqrt{x^2+m^2}\sim m+x^2/2m$ as $x\to 0$ in the argument of $g$, and evaluate the resulting integrals of the form

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \sin(kx)f(x)g\left(m+x^2/2m \right)
$$

on a case-by-case basis. This feels a little unnecessary, as I am only interested in the leading order behavior, but I am unsure of a better way to proceed.

Happy to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Usually the asymptotic behavior of the Fourier integral is linked to the regularity of the function. What is the regularity of $f$ and $g$ here? For example, if they are in $C^\infty$, then $f(x)\,g(\sqrt{x^2+m^2})$ is a Schwartz function, and so so is its Fourier transform. Hence it converges to $0$ faster than any polynomial.

Comment: @LL3.14 Does this apply if $f$ and $g$ are $C^\infty$ but their analytic continuations are not? Essentially, does having $g(\sqrt{x^2+m^2})$ matter at all?

Comment: I do not know what you are referring to as I do not know your functions, your problem is not clear if you do not give sufficiently many informations ... what is the regularity of your functions? Why are you speaking about analytic continuation? ...

Comment: @LL3.14 I've updated my question with the regularity of $f$ and $g$

Comment: @DogeChan That is true... but it tells us that $|I|<\infty$ because of the singularity at $x=0$ which was previously removed by $\sin(kx)$

Comment: @DogeChan $\int dx \ |f(x)| \ |g(\sqrt{\dots})|$ does not converge because $f \sim 1/x$ as $x \to 0$...